# is it possible to rename a sandbox by any technique

Tags: sandbox

Is it possible to rename a sandbox. I want to rename my UAT sandbox from ***** to UAT. is it possible

Comment: you can set name for sandbox during refreshing sandbox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can rename the sandbox while refreshing it.

Currently, there is no way to rename it without having to refresh. There is a idea posted in Salesforce community [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DtUMAA0), you can upvote it, so that Salesforce can take this up and provide us this feature in the coming releases.